# Implementing close_far solution logic

Tags: c#

It's been a while since I've used C# (2 years) and I'm trying to find the most efficient way to solve this problem.

> http://codingbat.com/prob/p160533

*Problem Statement:*

Given three ints, a b c, return True if one 
of b or c is "close" (differing from a by at most 1), 
while the other is "far", differing from both other 
values by 2 or more. Note: abs(num) computes the absolute value of a number.

close_far(1, 2, 10) → True
close_far(1, 2, 3) → False
close_far(4, 1, 3) → True

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

I'm just starting out, this is not for school, it's an exercise for work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In addition this isn't a code on demand site.  Please provide details on your attempt at solving the problem and what you need help with.

Comment: Added the question, I've yet to really try anything, I'd just like to start getting different ideas and takes on how others would do it. I'm starting it right now though.

Comment: I realize this isn't a code on demand site, it's just been a while and I'd like to see others take on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help? Though i am sure you must have worked out something like this.

```
public static bool Foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    var x = Math.Abs(a-b);
    var z = Math.Abs(c-a);

    var close = x>z?c:b;
    var far = x>z?b:c;

    return Math.Abs(close-a)<=1 
            && Math.Abs(far-a)>=2 
            && Math.Abs(far-close)>=2;
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I was doing, but I was not adding Math.Abs, why do you want to get the absolute value?


Also, I was doing mine more in 1 line, I like yours better, easier to read.

Comment: just caught my eye, `var y` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this:

```
    private static bool closeFar(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        bool bIsNear = Math.Abs(a - b) <= 1;
        bool cIsNear = Math.Abs(a - c) <= 1;
        if (!(bIsNear^cIsNear))
        {
            return false;
        }
        int far = bIsNear ? c : b;
        return Math.Abs(far - a) >= 2 && Math.Abs(c - b) >= 2;
    }
```

Just because this is one of the few times where I can use the XOR operator.